# WebRTC - Avoid renegotiation when adding track by replacing empty one

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm writing a WebRTC webapp that allows users to start on a voice call and add video while on an active call.

when adding/removing tracks a `negotiation` proccess is needed,
but not on replacing an exsiting track.

I'm trying to avoid the need of `negotiation` by using the the `replaceTrack` function,
but for that to work I need a "fake" video track,
I tried this but no constructor like this is exist:

```
const fakeTrack=new MediaStreamTrack()
```

I wondered if there is a solution that will avoid the need of the WebRTC `negotiation` while adding tracks,
maybe to pass it through a data channel..

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to avoid negotiation?